# Mesh in the real edges

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, edges

I am new to Blender, and I use Blender 3.3.6. I need help creating a mesh that looks like the mesh in the image given without having sub-divided edges.

I used the knife tool in the edit mode to cut an extruded mesh to get this mesh, but the created mesh is sub-dived as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by subdivided edges? Please make the question more clear. Secondly the mesh which you have shown probably has overlapping faces. Also is there a reference that you have? Will be much helpful if you provide that as well.

Comment: I am not sure how to say it. can you describe the steps to make the mesh in the image? please.

Answer (score 0):

For a quad based topology, you would divide the cube to 3 face loops, so you can lower the middle one. Then you would divide it also vertically, to at least 2 face loops*, so you can lower it to the nearest loop, using vertex snapping and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> *Extrude Manifold*:

[image]

*-I used 3 loops to get squares, but it's not very important, especially if you're about to scale the loops later in order to get the specific dimensions you want:

[image]

But it seems you want to get a minimum topology, meaning as few polygons as possible, and in this case you can just create a single face, and then extrude it:

[image]

<kbd>X</kbd> key to access the delete/dissolve menu, switch between vert, edge, face selection mode using <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> keys. Once you have the cube you can just dissolve unnecessary edges and vertices, as you saw at the beginning of the last gif.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.